# Javascript hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide a button on click using java-script. My code is not working for some reason here is the code. Everything works the alert pops up on the screen But no luck with the hide function.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Hello JQuery world!</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table class="data" id="celebs">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Approx. Location</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>Johnny</th>
        <th>Wrestler</th>
        <th>Knocksville</th>
        <th>500</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>Molly</th>
        <th>Pharmacist</th>
        <th>Germany</th>
        <th>1500</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>Scooby Doo</th>
        <th>Detective</th>
        <th>Jersey</th>
        <th>Scooby Snacks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <th>Pacman</th>
        <th>Character</th>
        <th>Area 51</th>
        <th>20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>Ryu</th>
        <th>Street Fighter</th>
        <th>Japan</th>
        <th>1891564</th>
     </tr>
      </tbody>

      </table>
      <input type="button" id="hideButton" value="hide" />
      <input type="button" id="disclaimer" value="hide" />
      </body>
     </html>
```

The java-script reads as followed

```
       $(function(){
        alert('Welcome');
         });

      $(function(){
 alert($('#celebs tbody tr:even').length + ' elements!');
      });
      $('#hideButton').click(function(){
$('#celebs').hide();
    });
    $(function(){
var fontSize = $('#celebs tbody tr:first').css('font-size');
alert(fontSize);
     });
   $(function(){
$('#celebs tbody tr:even').css('background-color', '#0C6');
    });
   $(function(){
$('#celebs tbody tr:odd').css({'background-color': '#930', 'color':'#C6F' }
    );
    });
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/VrQ56/1/

Comment: Hint: place all your jQuery in _one_ `$(function () { ... });` block

Comment: You have two buttons with value="hide". Are you clicking on the correct (left) button? :)

Comment: Works fine for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/AXvuE/

Answer (score 1):

Your event binding function is call before the document was load. So your event binding will not work. You should place your event binding functions in `(function(){..})` block.

```
$(function(){
        alert('Welcome');
        alert($('#celebs tbody tr:even').length + ' elements!');
        $('#hideButton').click(function(){
            $('#celebs').hide();
        });
        var fontSize = $('#celebs tbody tr:first').css('font-size');
        alert(fontSize);
        $('#celebs tbody tr:even').css('background-color', '#0C6');
        $('#celebs tbody tr:odd').css({'background-color': '#930', 'color':'#C6F' }
        );
    });
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. When jsFiddle loads jQuery "in `<head>`" (like the OP's code), it [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/AXvuE/1/). If you wrap the javascript in `(function(){...})`, it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/AXvuE/2/).